# How to parse List<SomeEntity> in jersey response.readEntity?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I have the client that makes a rest call to a server like this:

```
        Entity<RequestObject> entity = Entity.json(new RequestObject(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), Arrays.asList("xColumn", "yColumn")));

        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);

        Response response = client.target("http://172.18.0.1:10000/getProductsData")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.json(entity.getEntity()), Response.class);  

         List<WarehouseProductData> dwsData = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<WarehouseProductData>>(){});

        client.close();
```

The the other server is responding from the following method:

```
@PostMapping("/getProductsData")
public List<WarehouseProductData> greetingPost1(@RequestBody String json) {

WarehouseProductData wd = new WarehouseProductData(85654865);
wd.addData("xColumn", "value of product 85654865 for x column");
wd.addData("yColumn", "value of product 85654865 for y column");
wd.addData("the me column", "value of product 85654865 for 'the me column' column");
wd.addData("response for x", "1");
wd.addData("response for x", "2");

return Collections.singletonList(wd);
```

The WarehauseProductData class is like this:

```
public class WarehouseProductData {
        private int agoId;
    private Map<String, String> data;

    public WarehouseProductData(int agoId, Map<String, String> data) {
        this.agoId = agoId;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public WarehouseProductData(int agoId) {
        this.agoId = agoId;
        this.data = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public int getAgoId() {
        return agoId;
    }

    public void setAgoId(int agoId) {
        this.agoId = agoId;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Map<String, String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void addData(String columnName, String value) {
        data.put(columnName, value);
    }
```

}

The problem is that when the

```
List<WarehouseProductData> dwsData = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<WarehouseProductData>>(){});
```

is ran the dwsData is like this:

```
dwsData size = 1  
   |  
   --0 {WarehouseProductData}  
     |  
     -- agoId = 85654865  
     |  
     -- data = null (!!!which is incorect!!!)
```

So how to parse the response in order to get the `data` field correctly?

Comment: I don't know how that is even working without an no-arg constructor on your model class. Usually those are are needed for the deserializer to create an instance. Try to add one and see what happens.

Comment: I had added the no-args constructor, but got the same result. Do you have any more ideas about the situation?